# find a letter anywhere in an array of strings ios

Tags: ios

I have the method below for filtering some results:
Currently it does this:
array:  alpha, apple, aries, bravo

type a:

alpha
apple
aries

type l (now al)

alpha

I wanted to do this:

new search:
type p=
alPha
apple

below is the code

thank you kindly in advance

```
-(void) filterResults:(NSString *)searchText{
    NSMutableArray *test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.listContent];

    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.
        for (int i=0; i<[test count]; i++) {
            NSString *stringResult = [test objectAtIndex:i];
            NSComparisonResult result = [stringResult compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

            if (result == NSOrderedSame){
                [self.filteredListContent addObject:stringResult];

            }
        }
    [self.filteredListContent sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];//sort alphabetically
    NSLog(@"filtered results = %@",self.filteredListContent);
}
```

Comment: Check this question [NSPredicate to search NSStrings like SQL command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873855/nspredicate-to-search-nsstrings-like-sql-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the letter anywhere in your string, replace this:

```
NSComparisonResult result = [stringResult compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
if (result == NSOrderedSame){
    [self.filteredListContent addObject:stringResult];
}
```

with this:

```
NSRange range = [stringResult rangeOfString:searchText];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [self.filteredListContent addObject:stringResult];
}
```

Note that it will have to find **all** of the characters, in order.

If you want to find **any** of the characters, then use `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith '%@'", searchText]];
self.filteredListContent  = [self.listContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Hope this helps you.